# Is $(f(x_2 )-f(x_1 ))/(x_2-x_1 )=f'(c)$ for $f$ is continuous derivative on $(a,b)$, $x_1,x_2,c∈(a,b)$

Tags: calculus, proof-writing

Suppose that $f$ is continuous derivative on $(a,b)$, and let $c∈(a,b)$. Prove or disprove: there exist points $x_1,x_2∈(a,b)$ such that 
$(f(x_2 )-f(x_1 ))/(x_2-x_1 )=f'(c) $

This seem true, but I still have the feeling that it isn't true, but I can't give counter example that work for all $x_1,x_2$

Comment: Must be continuous in $[a,b]$

Comment: yes, that why I have the feeling that it's not true, but I can't prove it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it is not explicitly stated, $x_1 \neq x_2$ should be required, otherwise $\dfrac{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2-x_1}$ doesn't make sense.

Then a counterexample is given by $(a,b) = (-1,1)$, $c = 0$, and $f(x) = x^3$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=x,x\in [a,b)$ and $f(b)=2b$. So we suppose that $f$ is continuous on $[a,b)$(just to make it simpler),differentiable at  $(a,b)$. Then you cannot find any $c\in (a,b)$ from which you can drow a line parrallel to the line from $a$ to $b$ . So this is false.

Comment: @Diane Vanderwaif ,check my proof please.thank you